# Module Not Found Error: "langchain.chains.question_answering"

Tags: import, chatbot, document, langchain

I am trying to code a document chat bot using langchian. I installed the following first using :

```
$ pip install langchain langchain-openai pypdf openai chromadb tiktoken docx2txt*
```

When I run try to import `load_qa_chain` I got the following error

```
from langchain.chains.question_asnwering import load_qa_chain
```

```
Module Not Found Error: no module named langchain.chains.question_answering was found
```

Do I need to install anything else?
Please help!

I tried to install it separately using below code:

```
pip install langchain.chains.question_answering
```

but the Terminal response was:
[Terminal-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXPr1.png)

Answer (score 0):

while you are importing load_qa_chain you made a typo.

❌ Incorrect import statement

```
from langchain.chains.question_asnwering import load_qa_chain
```

✅ Correct import statement

```
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
```

Please follow the documentation [here](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/llms/sagemaker#for-cross-account-scenarios)